# How to change MsoLineJoinStyle with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm tring to create a rectangle in word 2016, and want to change the join style with VBA:

```vb
With ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, left, top, width, height)
        .Line.Weight = 11
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(32, 56, 100)
        .Line.Style = msoLineSingle
        '.Line.JoinStyle = msoLineJoinBevel
End With
```

It seems that the Line object doesn't have `JoinStyle` property, so how could I change it ?

I've checked the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.lineformat and I've also googled a lot, but didn't find the answer.

I want to change the JoinStyle by VBA, any help? Thanks.

Comment: If a property doesn't exist in the object model, you can't change it using VBA.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt thanks for the reply, as I read the document I found any line format could be modified by VBA but not JoinStyle, is this a missing feature or a bug? Or perhaps there is some other way to modify JoinStyle rather than changing property.

Comment: Not all UI features are included in the object model.

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway.